# How to connect Firebase database to Php scripts?

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an android app with Firebase database, and I am stuck at point when I want to connect that Firebase database with my own hosted Php scripts in which I want to perform some action on specific date , on that date it should delete some data from Firebase. FIrebase data on schedule(On specific date) so I am stuck at how to perform this how can be make this connection to firebase database with Php.

Using connection of php,  I want to made connection with firebase DB and want to retrieve and also delete some data from Firebase DB.

```
    <?php
 define('HOST','localhost');
 define('USERNAME', 'root');
 define('PASSWORD','');
 define('DB','insert2');

 $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USERNAME,PASSWORD,DB);

 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];

 $sql = "insert into users (username, password) values ('$username','$password')";

 if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
 echo 'success';
 }
?>
```

Please guide me. thanks

Comment: look : https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php/

Comment: https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html

Answer (score 1):

You can't connect to Firebase Database with the same way as MySQL.

You need to use one of these lib :

- [kreait/firebase-php](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php)
- [ktamas77/firebase-php](https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php)

Or use the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start).

Or create a Firebase Cloud Function which delete your wanted data and call it from the php with an [HTTP trigger](http://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).

Comment: thanks for replying for my problem.... and i want to perform little action... just on specific date delete tha little data from firebase.... should i need to do with js web pages?

Comment: You can use the Firebase Cloud Functions

Comment: Create a function which delete your wanted data and call it from the php. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events

Answer (score -1):

You can use this php code

```
$db = 'IP:C:/folders/files.FDB'; // Computer IP:Database file in drive and folders
$username = 'user';
$password = 'pass';
// Connect to database
$dbh = ibase_connect($db,$username,$password);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE';
// Execute query
$rc = ibase_query($dbh, $sql);
// Get the result row by row as object
while ($row = ibase_fetch_object($rc)) {
   echo $row->table_column;
}
// Release the handle associated with the result of the query
ibase_free_result($rc);
// Release the handle associated with the connection
ibase_close($dbh);
```

***And don't forget to install firebase extension to Web Server because it is not enabled by default.**

Comment: InterBase  is not Firebase.